# How to set click event on all div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I am having trouble with firing up same event on all DIVs which have class "card" as shown in below screenshot:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">CardClick</div>
      <div class="back">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set my handler as:

```
$(".card").click(function() {
    alert("clicked...");
});
```

Problem is that the alert box appears only for those DIVs marked as black in screenshot below. For all other boxes, line `alert("clicked...")` doesn't event execute.

Even the box marked as 5 in top row, has the alert box appear only if it is clicked in its top-right corner. Clicking any other place in this box doesn't fire up the alert. (Boxes in bottom row don't have this problem, Alert for them appear fine if clicked inside them anywhere).

Is this somehow related to Event Bubbling or Event Catching? How can I fix it such that the alert gets called for all DIVs with class "card"?

[image]

*Update:*
Related CSS look like following:

```
.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
    background: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    color:black;
}
.card .back {
    background: black;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.margin {
    margin-top: 200%;
}
```

*Update*
- Added HTML code to the question. Earlier I had a screenshot there. "col-md-1" etc. is how twitter bootstrap is helping laying out grid.

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle with your code HTML and CSS?

Comment: This problem may not be a js problem but rather a css/html problem.

Comment: Yeah, there are no clues on how you've styled the black and white cards differently. I suspect CardClick is the "dummy" div, and the black card is "card". So would be a HTML/CSS problem, where the "card" is just 0 width & height (no clickable target).

Comment: [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/whbvLem5/6/)

Comment: Where's the `click` class?

Comment: @KФ Just updated my question with the CSS rules I am using.

Comment: @Akurn Just updated my question with CSS used.

Comment: @baltusaj Yeah try and make a fiddle demonstrating your problem. I tried to recreate it with the code you've got, but it looks completely different to your screenshots, and my clicks are working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uar68hx7/. Could be a CSS or browser issue, which we can't see here.

Answer (score 3):

make sure to put your jquery/javascript code inside the document-ready function `$(function() { /* ..code.. */ });`. so you know that your divs are loaded into the `DOM` at the point where you want to apply your click-event:

```
$(function() {

    $("div.card").on("click", function(e){
        //your code here..
        alert("div with class 'card' clicked!");

        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent any other unwanted behavior clicking the div might cause
    });

});
```

***note:*** the selector `$("div.card")` only applies to divs with the class "card".

Comment: I have my JS code inside document `load` and I believe onload events gets triggered after `ready`, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @baltusaj ok, and you have corrected your selector in your question as i can see. and you still got the same problem? you really should try to reproduce your problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - i know it's a bit of work, but it really would help us out to support you.

Answer (score 2):

Friend,you can refer this, may be this will help you.
I have shown 3 ways of event binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/9kgq58fe/

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

/* option #1*/
    $(".card").click(function(){
        alert("you clicked " + $(this).attr("class") );
   }); 

   /* option #2*/ 
    $(".card").on('click',function(){
        alert("you clicked " + $(this).attr("class") );
    });
    /* option #3*/
       $(document).on('click','.card',function(){
        alert("you clicked " + $(this).attr("class") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> firing up same event on all DIVs which have class "card"

But you are binding it on `div`s with class `click`

change it to

```
$(".card").click(function() {
    alert("clicked...");
});
```

Comment: That was a typo on stackoverflow. Fixed it here now. Thanks for spotting. The code is binding it to .card

Answer (score 0):

You can set handler like this. so you will let to know that which card element you are clicking on. hope it will help you.

```
$(function(){
    $(".card").on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).text() + "clicked...");
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem if we change `$(".click").click(function() {` with `$(".card").click(function() {` as you want to add `click` event handler to all divs having class `card`. See below running code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".card").click(function() {
    alert("clicked...");
  });
});
```

```css
.margin {
    margin-top: 200%;
}
.card{
  max-width:40px;
  min-height:20px;
  background:cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
click on Divs below:

<div class="card margin">1</div> 
<div class="card margin">2</div>  
<div class="card margin">3</div>  
<div class="card margin">4</div>
```