# Select an element which is created dynamically without any events

Tags: jquery

I want to select multiple elements (`each`) which are created dynamically.

I know that I can do:

```
$('body').on('click', '.dynamically-created-element', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

The problem is that I do not have any events in here.

The second problem is that I need to use `each`.

So I'd like the code to look something like this:

```
$('body').on('ready', '.all-dynamically-created-elements', function () {
    forEachElemet(function () {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you add these dynamic elements?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem which could be better solved in another way. What is the actual issue you are trying to overcome with this logic?

Comment: @Eddie elements actually exist. they are just hidden. But the same problem is for elements loaded with ajax, after a timer.

Comment: So, without an event I can't really do this? Ok, but at least, how do I do a `each()` for those elements, like on the first code block in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to loop thru the dynamic elements when they are added and *ready* is using `.promise().done()`

```js
var newHTML = "<p class='dynamic-parag'>Par 1</p><p class='dynamic-parag'>Par 2</p><p class='dynamic-parag'>Par 3</p>";

$("div").html(newHTML).promise().done(function() {

  //Looping thru the dynamic <p class='dynamic-parag'> after they are added
  $('.dynamic-parag').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The problem is that `body` is substituted with the `newHTML` data, which is not ok.

Comment: @Lemures That is just an example. You can also `append`, that is why I asked you how do you add your dynamic HTML.

Comment: This is really good answer. The problem is that I have to keep in mind to insert the new html into the variable, then append it to the element. But the answer solves the issue. One more thing. Take a look at the first block of code in my question. Can you kindly tell me, how can I do an `each(function () { ... })` for those new elements?

Comment: You have to give a sample code of how you add the new HTML so that we can check it. We can't tell how to loop thru if you wont post it because we have no idea what are the new HTML elements are.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer link : 
[How to set click event on all div with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262480/how-to-set-click-event-on-all-div-with-same-class)

```js
 

    $(".dynamically").on("click", function(e){
        //your code here..
        console.log("div with class 'card' clicked!");

        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent any other unwanted behavior clicking the div might cause
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dynamically  {
 color : red
}
</style>
<div class="dynamically" > div 1</div>
<div class="dynamically" > div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this aproach ...

You will catch every click in a dynamic created element and you will have the event object.

```
$(".dynamically").bind( "click", function(event) {
      alert("The div " + event.target.innerText+ " was clicked.");
});


<div class="dynamically">div 1</div>
<div class="dynamically">div 2</div>
```